# WebApp crashing when connecting through a nginx websocket proxy

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, websocket

I have a very weird situation with docker/nginx and websockets, 
I proxy through nginx to a websocket server and every time i close the connection the server crashes.

If i connect directly to the websocket server and close the connection its all fine.

If I run the websocket server through Xcode and nginx to that and close the connection it all works fine too.

I have check all the linux dependancies and none of them have been upgraded since Sept 2019 (only started to happen last night)

Commands to cause

```
var s = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080/socket", "zara")
s.close();
```

Crash Dump Log

```
zaraapp_1  | * thread #7, name = 'issueServer', stop reason = signal SIGPIPE
zaraapp_1  |     frame #0: 0x00007ffff76832b7 libpthread.so.0`__libc_write + 71
```

**EDIT

Updated all docker images and now it only happens when you refresh the brower (tested in Safari and Chrome)

Doesnt happen with IE

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was the debugging tool allowing the SIGPIPE to go through even thought it was ignored in the code